# Function calls, the stack

Tags: c, stack

So I don't know why but I learned that when you call a function and pass an argument to it, it deals with it on the stack(processor?).

Can someone please explain it?

then how does it change values of variables, blocks of memory and so on?

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that parameters are passed on the stack, it's architecture and compiler dependent.

As to how values and memory get changed -- when you call a function that must make changes that are seen by the caller, it's normal that what you provide is not the actual value, but rather the address of (pointer to) that value. As long as the function knows the proper memory location it can make these changes.

Comment: Yes thank you!  now I see that it is called passing by value, and by reference. So it says that when you pass by value the function operates on a value that has been copied to the stack. so why do you ever need to pass by value?

Comment: Pass by value is safer. When the function you are calling has no need to modify the value, if you pass by reference then the caller must either be very careful or risk corrupting data that the callee isn't expecting to change. This is the normal case, where a true need for pass by reference is less frequent.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. If you want your variable value should not change after the funciton call... you send it by value. And if you want them to change... you send it by reference  or pointer. For ex, arrays are always passed by pointer.

Comment: I mean you always want to use a function so that it modifies part of your program state.

Comment: One person voted up, someone else voted down (implying my answer was incorrect -- but apparently lacking the willingness to explain their concern.

Comment: I can't see who voted, but I can see that I currently have 18 points on this answer. Upvotes are +10 each, downvotes are -2 each. Accepted answers are +15 each. My two upvotes = 20 points, down to 18 for the downvote, and my answer has not been accepted as the answer.

Comment: @mah  Hi, your answer, and then the comments have been very helpful. I don't know which answer to choose as the accepted answer. but both yours and stupid's were helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

Stack is used in most cases to pass arguments to function. The reason for using it is that you are not bound to fixed memory places (for arguments) to have your function functional. If you had function that could take arguments from fixed memory you would probably only be able to run it if the memory was free and you would be able to run just one instance of it. Stack gives you the possibility to store your arguments to current context of your program at any time. On x86 processors there is register that points to end of the stack and other register that points to the begining. Those are actualy just addresses to main memory where you want your stack to reside.

There is PUSH instruction that moves the stack-end register to the next place and stores specified data (could be value from other register or at some address or direct value) to address pointed by stack-end resgister. The other instruction is POP and it works the same just the other way around. This way, if you stick to the plan and keep track of what you pushed to stack, you can have your functions work from any context.

There are some other less used options to pass arguments like via registers, which are used for example by bios interrupts. If you want to know more about this I suggest you read something on "Calling conventions".

Comment: Very good explanation!! I understand now. But i didn't understand what you meant here: "This way, if you stick to the plan and keep track of what you pushed to stack, you can have your functions work from any context. "

Comment: Umm.. this part is actually something that is done by compiler for you. If you pass the arguments with stack, your compiler pushes them on stack and after that it refers to them as stack-end register +4 +8 +12 and so on.. It could happen that you passed something like (int, int, char, short int, int) which is a little bit messy to address because char is just 1 byte and short int are 2 bytes. So it would be addressed like +8 +12 +13 +15 +19.. thats what i meant by keeping track on what you push to stack. (Arguments start on +8 because usualy compiler pushes two other ints before arguments)

Comment: I wouldn't call passing arguments via registers a "less used option" since it is commonly used, for example, on x86-64.

Comment: well... I would :D , talking about x86 I think the default calling convention produced by cl.exe and mingw is cdecl. It is totally possible that I just dont know about it but, at what commonly used function did you last see register or fastcall as calling convention?

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with this suppose you have a function

```
int foo(int value) {
   int a = 10;
   return a;
}
```

So whenever a function call is made OS needs some memory space to allocate the local variables of the function `int a` in this case and arguments to the function passed `int value` in this case. This memory requirement is fulfilled by allocating memory on stack. A stack is nothing but a memory region allocated to each process and it actually behaves as a stack data structure(LIFO).

Now the question arises what all things are stored on stack when a function call is made. The first thing pushed on the stack are the arguments passed to the function in reverse order(if more then one).
2. Then the return address of the function which called this function (because once this function `foo` completes execution it should return back to the place in the code from where it was called)
3. Finally local variables of the function called are pushed on the stack.

Once the called function completes executing the code it returns back to the return address previously stored on the stack and thus we say function call completes or returns.
In this case the function has a return value which it passes back to the callee function.
The space is then free to use and can be overwritten in the subsequent function calls.

(Now if you connect the dotes you can realize why local variables(automatic variables) in a function have scope limited to the life of the function call (you asked a SO question related to scope which was closed) because once a call returns the memory space allocated for these locale variable is gone(it is still there but you cant access them once a function returns) so life of these automatic variable `int a` in this case limits till `foo()` returns to the callee function.

Side Note:: I have read many questions that you have posted in SO. I guess you are trying to learn C and basic working of the underlying hardware and OS in general and the confusion in between them is killing you. 
I would suggest you some pointers apart from the answer to this question to read and understand which will give you lots of insight into the questions you are facing.

1. For C refer K&R it is the best book.
2. In the starting read little bit about OS concepts(Memory handling, Virtual Memory in particular)
3. Try imagine the working of a system in broad sense as in how different components are interacting.
4. Some good links for understanding memory related stuff and system internals http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/best-of

and if you want to dive into stack space for a function call try this link http://www.binarypirates.in/2011/02/17/understanding-function-stack-in-c/

Hope this helps